# Strange default constructor syntax

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Saw the following in some legacy code:

```
class A {
    &A() { ... }
}
```

What "&" is used for? It compiles in VC++ 2008 and looks like default constructor,
bug gcc fails to compile it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although syntactically `&` is allowed in this position in the grammar (it's an example of a *declarator* that is the sequence: *ptr-operator declarator*, `&` being a *ptr-operator*), semantically it has no meaning and is not allowed here. The fact that it is valid purely from a grammatical point of view may indicate why Visual Studio might accept it.

Examining the possiblities, this declaration looks like a function definition with no return type. 7 [dcl.dcl]/6 says: "Only in function declarations for constructors, destructors and type conversions can the *decl-specifier-seq* be ommitted." and there being no `~` or `operator` the only possibility is a constructor declaration.

12.1 [class.ctor] / 1 describes the special declarator syntax used for constructors and it must only be an optional sequence of *function-specifiers* followed by the constructor's class name. No `&` or other *ptr-operator* is allowed before the constructor's class name.